# Using WPF UI element property value in ViewModel with ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I'm not really sure if this is a WPF or RxUI issue, so I just show my code and then explain my problem.

MainWindowView.xaml

```xml
<reactiveui:ReactiveWindow ...
                           Height="840"
                           Width="800"
                           ResizeMode="CanMinimize">

    <DockPanel>
        <!-- Some stuff in the main dock panel -->
        <Border BorderThickness="5"
                DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <DockPanel>
                <!-- Other stuff in inner dock panel -->                
                <Grid Height="100"                      
                      Background="Black"
                      DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                      Margin="0 10 0 0">                   
                    <Image x:Name="UI_WaveformImage"
                           Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=Width}"
                           Stretch="Fill">                     
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</reactiveui:ReactiveWindow>
```

MainWindoeView.xaml.cs

```cs
public MainWindowView ()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    this.WhenActivated(d =>
    {
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Waveform.Image, v => v.UI_WaveformImage.Source).DisposeWith(d);
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.UI_WaveformImage.ActualWidth).BindTo(this, x => x.ViewModel.WaveformWidth).DisposeWith(d);
    });
}
```

MainWindowVieModel.cs

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject, IEnableLogger
{
    public ReactiveCommand<string, AudioWaveformImage> GenerateNewWaveform { get; }
    
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<AudioWaveformImage> _waveform;
    public AudioWaveformImage Waveform => _waveform.Value;
    
    public int WaveformWidth { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel ()
    {
        GenerateNewWaveform = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<string, AudioWaveformImage>(p => GenerateNewWaveformImageImpl(p));
        GenerateNewWaveform.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex => {
            this.Log().Error("GenerateNewWaveform command failed to execute.", ex);
        });
        
        _waveform = GenerateNewWaveform.ToProperty(this, nameof(Waveform), scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
(1)     GenerateNewWaveform.Execute(AudioFilePath).ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
(2)     this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.AudioFilePath)
            .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
            .InvokeCommand(GenerateNewWaveform);
    }

    private async Task<AudioWaveformImage> GenerateNewWaveformImageImpl (string path)
    {
        UIOutput.AppendLine($"Waveform width start: {WaveformWidth}");
        var wf = new AudioWaveformImage(WaveformWidth == 0 ? 100: WaveformWidth, 100, 100, Colors.CornflowerBlue, Colors.Red, path);
        await Task.Delay(10);
        //await wf.Update();
        UIOutput.AppendLine($"Waveform width end: {WaveformWidth}");
        return wf;
    }
}
```

Just a bit of explanation:
`UIOutput.AppendLine()` just displays info in a textbox for me. I use it for debugging, but its purpose is to let the end-user know the progress of what's going on.
`AudioWaveformImage` is initialized with the desired size, colors, and path to the file that I want the waveform of. So, I need to know the size of the Image element I want to display it in.

So here's my problem:
The first time `GenerateNewWaveformImageImpl()` is executed on program startup, via line (1), `UIOutput` shows "Waveform width start: 0" and "Waveform width end: 0". After I change `AudioFilePath` and `GenerateNewWaveformImageImpl()` gets run a second time, via line (2), I get the correct width as `UIOutput` shows "Waveform width start: 776" and "Waveform width end: 776". Now I know I could hard code that, but that doesn't help when the window gets resized.

Why is the correct Width not being reported when the app first runs?

Comment: Maybe because `(1)` is called in the VM constructor, and your VM constructor is called before your bindings?

Answer (score 2):

Try to invoke the command once the view model has been activated:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject, IEnableLogger, IActivatableViewModel
{
    public ViewModelActivator Activator { get; } = new ViewModelActivator();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.WhenActivated((CompositeDisposable disp) => 
        {
            //invoke command...
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and still reports width = 0 on startup

Comment: Maybe you should consider to provide a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your issue then?

Comment: How and where do you set the width?

Comment: I set it in MainWindowView.xaml, as shown in my OP. I've tried leaving the width property blank, I've tried setting it to a literal value (300), and I've tried what is shown in my OP.

Comment: The view binds to the view model. It's not the other way around.

Comment: But on RxUI's docs, they say that you can use ```BindTo``` to bind view to viewmodel if needed.

https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/#hack-bindings-and-bindto

Comment: Otherwise, I'd be letting the view model determine the state of the view. I'm still pretty novice with this whole MVVM thing, but I thought the ViewModel was only supposed to handle the business end of things, and layout was the job of the view. So I want the view to determine how big of an image it can accommodate.

Comment: A target property of the view binds to a source property of a view model. The view model does determine the state of the view. That's the point of it.

Comment: but if the target property (Image.width) of the view is set based on a source property in the view model, then the viewmodel is determining the state of the view.

Comment: btw. my efforts to understand things are often misconstrued with arguing... I'm not arguing, just trying to understand.

Comment: Again, the viewmodel *is* and should be determining the state of the view. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the main problem in your original code is that you're invoking `GenerateNewWaveform` in the VM `constructor`. At this point, your `Width` has NOT been bound to your property yet, as witnessed here:

```
public MainWindowView () {
    // Constructor happens first.
    ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    this.WhenActivated(d => {
        // Binding to Width happens later..
        this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.UI_WaveformImage.ActualWidth)
          .BindTo(ViewModel, vm => vm.WaveformWidth)
          .DisposeWith(d);
    });
}
```

The answer that suggested using a `ViewModelActivator` will not work either, because `ViewModel.WhenActivated` is triggered *before* `View.WhenActivated`. I.e. Same issue as above. The command in the VM will be invoked before the Width binding in the View.

One way to solve this is to invoke your command *after* the Width binding.

```
public MainWindowView () {
    ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();  // Constructor..

    this.WhenActivated(d => {
        // Bind to Width..

        // Tell the VM to invoke, after Width is bound..
        ViewModel.GenerateNewWaveform.Execute(...);
    });
}
```

If you don't like having the View telling the VM what to do, because it's iffy, you could have the VM do `WhenAnyValue(_ => _.WaveformWidth)`, filtering by `> 0`, and doing a `Take(1)`. This will allow you to invoke when your VM receives the first non-zero width after the binding.